# Python: добавление CSV в таблицу postgreSQL, проверка дубликата

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

Помогите пожалуйста, как добавить проверку на существующий дубликат уникального ключа, если есть пропустить и импортировать строки с CSV дальше.
Ошибка:

> `psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates uniqueconstraint "dbname_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists.`

```
import psycopg2
def importoDB(self):
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect( host='ip', user='username', 
    password='pass', 
    dbname='dbname')
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    f = open(r'test.csv', 'r')
    self.cursor.copy_from(f, 'dbname', sep=';')
    f.close()
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: 1- загружайте во временную таблицу: `copy_from(file=f, table='tmp_table', sep=';)` 2- объединить таблицы: `'insert into "table" select * from "tmp_table"  on conflict do nothing'`. Связанный вопрос [To ignore duplicate keys during 'copy from' in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13947327/4279)